# import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito not found?

Tags: java, import

Please guide to fix this issue.

`import org.mockito.Mockito`;  works fine

`import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;` **org not found**

`import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;` works fine

`import org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockTestCase;` works fine

`import static org.junit.Assert.*;`

Comment: Fixed . i was including wrong jar.

Comment: i'm facing this issue and i got power mockito from maven, and cant find this class !!

Answer (score 2):

I know the issue is fixed but if you're using Maven, you need to include this as well:[powermock-api-mockito](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.7.4)